# get selected id value of multiselect dropdown binds from database in jquery

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller, multi-select

i have a multi select dropdown list binds from database i want to get the id of the selected value

i tryed to use jquery function to get array of selected values but it never works

My html code

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RolesMenusMain, GlobalLists.GetMenus(),
         new { @class = "form-control select2 multiple", multiple = "multiple", selectedvalue = selected })
```

jquery  Code

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2').select2({
            width: '100%'
        });
        debugger;
        var IDs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",").length; i++) {
            if ($("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",")[i] != "")
                IDs.push($("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",")[i]);
            alert(IDs);
        }

        $("#RolesMenusMain").val(IDs).trigger("change");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok and should work as shown in the following snippet. Make sure that the variable `selected` is a string containing the ids separated by a comma.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2').select2({
            width: '100%'
        });
        debugger;
        var IDs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",").length; i++) {
            if ($("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",")[i] != "")
                IDs.push($("#RolesMenusMain").attr("selectedvalue").split(",")[i]);
            alert(IDs);
        }

        $("#RolesMenusMain").val(IDs).trigger("change");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="RolesMenusMain" multiple="multiple" class="select2" selectedvalue="1,2,3">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use pseudo Selector `:selected` to get the selected option.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  const selectedOption = $('select option:selected')[0];
  console.log(selectedOption);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="garden">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option>Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
```